# Integral signs not being rendered correctly

Tags: bug, mathjax

Some integral signs on M.SE are not rendering correctly for me. I've been having this problem for at least a few months, and it persists when I refresh the page. The problem is rare but frequent enough that it's annoying.

> [image]

As you can see, the top part of the integral sign is cut off. This is a screenshot of a section of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105276/differential-equations-and-fourier-and-laplace-transforms/105837#105837). I have also had this happen on questions and answers I have posted.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? What should I do about it?

I'm on the most recent version of Safari.

Edit: Following the advice of Martin Sleziak, I tried to replicate this bug in the non-default renderers (SVG and MathML). They both render integrals correctly. I conclude that this is a problem with the HTML-CSS renderer.

Comment: Could you link to a page where you see this happening?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Done. See my edit.

Comment: Debug Check: Does not duplicate on latest chrome nor latest IE on a Win 7 SP1. Does not duplicate in safari on iphone with ios 6 **for me**. My pet bug is that on TeX edit in chrome the font is silly big, but a refresh always fixes this. Best of luck. Try isolating the bug to the browser brand.

Comment: What is your choice in the MathJax menu under Math Settings/Math Renderer. Does it influence whether this bug appears? (See [this image](http://www.opticsinfobase.org/ao//images/MathJax-Renderer.jpg) if you cannot find the menu.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the tip. Please see my edit.

Comment: Where does one find the MathJax menu?

Comment: @GEdgar Right-click a piece of rendered MathJax, then follow the menus shown by Martin Sleziak above.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I saw this too.  Safari 7.0.1 on Mac OS 10.9.  The first time I noticed it was yesterday.

[THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/130625/442)

[image: picture]

**edit Jan 25, 2014**

Today it happened [HERE](https://mathoverflow.net/a/155585/454) in Mathoverflow:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. Do you see this consistently?

Comment: On that answer, with the HTML-CSS renderer, Safari does that integral in the defective manner.  Other integrals (even the same size, later in the same line) are OK.  But yes, it is consistent with that particular integral.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on the same setup but I opened an issue to see if anyone else can, see https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/710

Comment: OK, I switched back to HTML-CSS, and the problem is gone for me.  So, what has changed since Dec 23?

Comment: Nothing that we're aware of. It may have been a cached file that was tripping things up for you. Let us know on the bug tracker if you run into this again.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger ... A new instance today in MO ... https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5513/454

Comment: Thanks for connecting the dots between this post and [that one](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5513)!

Comment: @GEdgar I don't work for MathJax anymore. From the looks of it, stackexchange still uses MathJax v2.7.5 which is now over 4 years old (and woefully out of date - v4 is in alpha status right now). So you probably want to start by getting SE to update.