# mathjax stops when I'm editing this question

Tags: bug, mathjax

I'm encountering this strange behave of the mathjax-system with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096669/borel-laplace-transform-and-psi-function) .
Everything is fine if I refresh this page in my browser (Firefox) ; but when I start editing the text then the preview stops rendering mathjax, and also after saving the page will be shown without mathjax-rendering. After refreshing the page everything looks ok again. (I've restarted the browser, but the behave did not improve, so I think I've treated mathjax to run into a bug...

---

***[update]: I've copied the text of my question in an answer box so you need not move to the main-site to test the behave***

Comment: Very strange, I have the same problem on Chrome.

Comment: You should probably mention that [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19123/mathjax-v2-5-beta-released).

Comment: @Daniel : done ${  }$

Comment: This happens to me quite a lot when I am making an answer with a lot tex.

Comment: Same on Internet Explorer. It must be a site problem.

Comment: Having the same issue on Internet Explorer.  It seems like once a certain length is reached, it stops updating.  I've had to cut at least one answer short because I could no longer see what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

***For the opportunity of testing I include here just the original text of my question. Perhaps try to edit/update this "answer" to isolate the point from where the bug can be reproduced***

I'm ölk considering some family of functions whose coefficients of their power series occur in the columns of the following matrix **A**
$ \qquad $ [image: picture]

The second of that functions is 
$$  f_1(x) = - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \zeta(1-k) x^k $$
By evaluating it numerically for various $x$ using Noerlund sums I arrived at the guessed closed-form expression for it as
$$  f_1(x) = \log(1/x) - \psi(1/x) $$

- Sanity-check: if I feed the following in W/A
  $$ \text{series [ log(t) - digamma(t) ]} $$
  I get the same series, however in the form for some leading coefficients from which I conclude 
  $$  [f_1(1/t) =] \quad  \sum_{k=1}^\infty -\zeta(1-k) \frac 1{t^k} \qquad \qquad \text{ expansion at } t=\infty$$
  so it appears that the guessed closed-form is correct.

---

I have now the next function 
$$  f_2(x) =  \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_{2,k} x^k  $$
where the compositions of the $a_{2,k}$ is of $\zeta()$-values form the above, but with some pattern. On searching for a closed form for this I'm stuck.

---

To understand the pattern in the $a_{2,k}$ I've found a very elegant solution, but I can't do the final step. It involves Borel- or Laplace-transformation and -reversion.

The Borel-transformation of the series representation of $f_1(x)$ is
$$  F_1(x) = - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \zeta(1-k) {x^k \over k! }  $$
and this has a closed form
$$  F_1(x) = \log( {\exp(x)-1\over x}) $$
Now the "elegant moment" is, that the Borel-transformation of the series representation of $f_2(x)$ 
$$  F_2(x) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_{2,k} \frac {x^k}{k!}  $$
has simply the closed form
$$ F_2(x) = (F_1(x))^2 $$ 
and moreover, for all following $k>2$ it is 
$$ F_k(x) = (F_1(x))^k  $$

The problem is now that I don't know how to find from this the closed form for $f_2(x)$ (or $f_k(x)$ for higher $k$. W/A was of no help here.

> ***Q1:*** What is the closed form for $f_2(x)$ and that of the following members of that family of functions?

---

Additional remark: I'm not experienced with Borel- or Laplace-transform. But while Pari/GP has a function *"serlaplace()"* and this gives the expected transformation from $F_k(x)$ to $f_k(x)$ and I could experiment with this a bit, W/A gives another thing when called *"laplacetransform()"* , actually it gave $f_1(x)/x$ instead $f_1(x)$. So question 2:

> ***Q2:*** What is the correct expression for the series-forward&backward transformations: Borel? Laplace?

*P.s.: I'm not good with tagging of questions like this. Please don't hesitate to improve the tagging if not optimal*

Comment: I've removed the `\tag{}` -function and the `\small` - directives, but that alone does not cure the problem